# Visual Studio: How to figure out where this type is defined?

Tags: visual-studio

i have an interface - one of whose members returns a variable of type**Object**.

In my attempts to try to use this returned variable, i discovered that it isn't just an "**Object**", but is actually a "**mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass**", as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

In my case, this is perfect, since it appears (through code-insight), that the object then supports many of the methods and properties i'm actually trying to use (that i was about to use through late binding).

**The question is:**

- Where is this type coming from?
- Where is it defined

so i may convert my code from:

```
object webDocument = ie.Document;
```

to

```
mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass webDocument = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)ie.Document;
```

---

If you're wondering, **ie** is declared as:

```
IWebBrowser2 ie;
```

and IWebBrowser2's declaration of ie.Document is:

```
[ComImport, DefaultMember("Name"), 
      Guid("D30C1661-CDAF-11D0-8A3E-00C04FC9E26E"), 
      InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch),
      SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public interface IWebBrowser2
{
   ...
   object Document { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] [DispId(0xcb)] get; }
   ...
}
```

So it's an **Object**, that also supports **IDispatch**. Nowhere in any of my code is mentioned a type called "mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass".

**Note:** If you think it can be cast to

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument
```

you would be mistaken.

---

If you're wondering why i'm doing this, then change all variable names and class types into random strings to obfuscate the example.

---

[chakrit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484770/visual-studio-how-to-figure-out-where-this-type-is-defined#484830) suggested using "*Go to Definition** of the **ie.Document** member, which unfortunatly goes to the declaration of ie.Document:

[image]

And also the declaration of **Object** brings me to the declaration of **Object**:

[image]

---

[chakrit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484770/visual-studio-how-to-figure-out-where-this-type-is-defined#484830) had a really good suggestion:

```
public static string TellMeAboutThisObject(object obj)
{
   Type t = obj.GetType();
   Assembly asm = t.Assembly;

   return 
         "Type Name: "+t.FullName+Environment.NewLine+
         "Namspace: " + t.Namespace+Environment.NewLine+
         "From assembly: "+ asm.FullName+Environment.NewLine+
         "Located at: "+asm.Location;
}
```

Which in my case returns:

> **Type Name:** mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
>
> **Namspace:** mshtml
>
> **From assembly:** Microsoft.mshtml, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>
> **Located at:** C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.mshtml\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.mshtml.dll

So, in my case it's the damnest thing that someone is automagically adding a reference to a managed assembly - when i was trying to interop with COM directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Object.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) method to obtain information about a particular object you got.

Here's an example:

```
using System;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new { Random = "Object" } as object;

        var t = obj.GetType();

        var asm = t.Assembly;

        Console.WriteLine("Type name     : " + t.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("Namspace      : " + t.Namespace);
        Console.WriteLine("From assembly : " + asm.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("Located at    : " + asm.Location);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Or in your case...

```
var t = ie.Document.GetType()
```

...should give you type information about what is it that is really inside `ie.Document`.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search on MSDN gets me to this page which describes how to get the document interface:
[About MSHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508515(VS.85).aspx)
Note: I cannot try any of this as I am stuck with VS.80

Comment: Ok, so it was actually Ubiquity - google command, but the first result was a MSDN page.

Comment: Problem with that is it doesn't apply to .NET. There is no IDispatch interface type that you can query for IHTMLDocument2.

Comment: That's a wholly different usage than it was probably intended then; in that case, good luck

Answer (score 1):

A little confused about what is it that you're trying to accomplish.

Can you not use the "**Go to Definition**" context menu in Visual Studio to bring up the **Object Browser** to locate the type?

[go to definition http://chakrit.net/files/temp/so_go_to_definition.png](http://chakrit.net/files/temp/so_go_to_definition.png)

Comment: What am i going to the definition of. Object? ie.Document? Those bring me to the declaration of Object and IWebDocument2.Document respectivly - not to the declaration of {mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass}.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a reference to **Microsoft.mshtml**. 'Nuff said.

**Added:** OK, a few more words - .NET programs operate with COM objects through these interop assemblies. If you add a reference to a COM object in Visual Studio, VS generates one for you. For the WebBrowser there is already one pre-generated, because it's so often used. But you can't operate with COM "directly". Well, maybe you can, but that would be masohistic.

Comment: Problem with that is that now the customer must have Microsoft.mshtml assembly.

Comment: Perhaps, but that doesn't stop the application from crashing when the exact same version of Microsoft.MsHtml PIA is not installed.

Comment: Then you've missed the point of GAC. It contains many versions of the same DLL, so your application can choose EXACTLY the one it needs. In other words - you can depend on this PIA to be there as much as you can depend on the framework being there.

Comment: "Problem with that is that now the customer must have Microsoft.mshtml assembly." I would not think that you could have it both ways. Either you are going to reference and use the type, or you aren't...